# run second instance of a WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, multiple-instances

There is this ([Business Directory Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/business-directory-plugin/)),

The question is, is it possible to run a second instance of this plugin to run another type of directory in same WordPress installation (not multi-site)?

Tried to bulk rename classes and hooks..etc, but no luck.
Is there a plugin that support this behavior or some hint?

It was possible to reach [one post](http://awpcp.com/questions-answers/can-i-install-multiple-instances-of-the-plugin-on-the-same-site/) stating it could be possible for a different plugin.

Any help appreciated ,

Thank you.

**Update:**

Just to clarify the point of the question/solution:

I want to run multiple directory in my WordPress Installation

- One for Medicine Directory
- The other for Medicine Agents/Marketers Directory

Each directory has its own fields and content

Anyhow, I found the solution bellow
Thanks for all help

Comment: Maybe you're looking for Multisite Wordpress?

Comment: Thanks for your input @Eduardo, I want to run this on single WP installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution and it worked like charm without any errors!!!!

I used `notepad++` to search all files and did a bulk replace `classes` and main plugin's keywords (`custom type and meta slugs' names and all possible duplicates` ) into 2nd instance names.

I uploaded the plugin into WordPress single installation and it was activated successfully and I was able to add new custom posts and new custom meta data...

Here is a screenshot of second instance of my plugin.....its is possible to do it and it worked like charm!!!

[image: Its possible and doable]
Back end First and Second Instance

[image: proof of concept]
Back end

[image: Front End First Instance]
Front End First Instance

[image: Front End Second Instance] 
Front End Second Instance

After I figure it out , it took from me 10 min to run another instance of the plugin

Thank you

**Update:**
I was even able to link between the two instance entries

Off course I had also to create another instance of the `Shortcode`!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not if they're using post types and taxonomies that are regiatered through the plugin. You could probably extend the plugin functionality and create your own post type.

Comment: Thanks @Harry for your input, actually it is possible and doable...please refer to screenshot...I was able to manage it, can't be sure about all other plugins..but this one worked!!!!